# Converting a text to date in VBA results in a time value

Tags: excel, vba, date

I noticed a strange phenomenon in Excel today. We were testing a new Add-In on the client's PC (Windows 10, german locale, Excel 2016). The VBA Add-In searches the first column for dates formatted as "dd.mm.yy" (german date format), then uses those dates for something else after converting them to Date type.

```
Dim targetDate as Date: targetDate = CDate(cellValue). 'cellValue is "05.04.18"
```

When checking the value of the variable, it was shown as "05:04:18" (a time format).

We ended up replacing the "." with "-", so that `IsDate()` function worked, then formatted the value with `Format(cellValue, "dd-mm-yy")` to make it work.

But does anyone know we Excel didn't recognize the date value as a date? The "mm.dd.yy" format wasn't the default "short date" format according the windows settings, but shouldn't Excel recognize it anyway?

The column with the dates was formatted as "Default".

Comment: Interesting question indeed. Noticed similar things using a Dutch locale once. They are most likely the same. If i manually select short date as data type in excel conversion to short-date notation goes well.

Comment: Does the cell contain a *date* value or a *string*?

Comment: If you are refering to a value in a cell use `.Value2`: `Range("A1").Value2`  this will return the numeric value of the date not the date, which vba will know how to use.  Remember that vba is EN-US centric.  In that it will take strings and parse them how it would  be parsed in the US, so it sees the string `"05.04.18"` as a time and not a date.

Comment: @FunThomas: It's formatted as default and contains "05.04.18". I'm assuming it is saved as a string. But changing the cell format to Date did not change the value in the cell or the result of the test.

Comment: Then it is a string and not a date and you will need to parse the parts of the string.  vba is taking it's best guess.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Interesting, I forgot the difference between Value2 and Value. Though, as said in my comment to FunThomas, the value of the cell doesn't seem to be saved in Excels "large number that represents a date" way. Instead, it is saved as a string value.

Comment: Given a `Date` (recognized as such) value, `.Value2` will give you the `Double` underlying value, and `.Value` will give you a `Date` value. If the cell isn't recognized as a date, then both will give you a *string that looks like a date*.